# Scrapy - How to define structure of the csv export (columns,etc..)

Tags: scrapy, export-to-csv

I am quite new with scrapy, and i'm to figure out how to set the structure of a csv export. I have in the following example 2 kind of data scraped: ids and links

Here is the simple code i'm using :

```
class MybotSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mybot'
    start_urls = ['url']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_dataids = response.css('li::attr(data-id)').extract()
        all_links = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "js_clickable")]/@href').extract()

        adlist = SpiderItem()
        adlist['dataid'] = all_dataids
        adlist['link'] = all_links
        yield adlist
```

But my export is like this :

[image: csv_export_i_get]

instead, i would like to export with for each id corresponding the href and separated in rows :

[image: csv_export_i_would_like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make yielding items in this way:

```
def parse(self, response):
    all_dataids = response.css('li::attr(data-id)').extract()
    all_links = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "js_clickable")]/@href').extract()

    for link, dataid in zip(all_links, all_dataids):
        adlist = SpiderItem()
        adlist['dataid'] = dataid
        adlist['link'] = link
        yield adlist
```

Here you `zip` your arrays to `((link, dataid), (link, dataid), (link, dataid), ...)` and then yielding them one by one. So it should give you desired output.

Comment: I thought i tried this but actually, it works perfectly, many thanks for your help vezunchik